# Easiest way to connect to Joomla 2.5 database and get a Category ID

Tags: php, joomla, easyblog

**My Situation**

Im very new to Joomla and I installed a component called EasyBlog. What Im trying to do is get `category_id` from `jos_easyblog_post` table for a particular `post_id` and  and `echo` it on the template. Im also not quite sure if its ok to put database connection script on the template itself?

`jos_easyblog_post` has few columns,

```
id - Post Id
category_id - Category that post belongs to
Hits etc etc.
```

Lets say `id` which is Post ID is 5 and how can I conenct to the database and go to `jos_easyblog_post` and look for the post `id` 5 and get the `category_id` associated with it? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joys of using a CMS such as Joomla, is that scripts become easy. Connecting to the database is done using the code below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

To get results from a database table using Joomla 2.5 standards, you can try something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('category_id')
 ->from('#__easyblog_post')
 ->where('post_id = 5');
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadResult();

echo $row;
```

Note that when defining a Joomla database table, the prefix is defined as `#__`

Comment: Hi Lodder. Thanks. There was a `;` missing at the end of `$query` i guess. Also the output says just `Array`. Why is that?

Comment: @nasty - ah sorry, my mistake. I have updated my answer with the additional `;` and changed `loadObjectList` to `loadResult`. This will definitely work